# Out-FINcodedCommand.ps1 is not recognized - executing a script in the current directory

Tags: powershell, execution

I have seen this script https://github.com/danielbohannon/Out-FINcodedCommand/blob/master/README.md

And when I try the the example given I get the error

```
Out-FINcodedCommand.ps1 : The term 'Out-FINcodedCommand.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that
the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
Out-FINcodedCommand.ps1 -command "iex (iwr https://github.com/danielb ...
CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (Out-FINcodedCommand.ps1:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you running it.  Add .\ in front of it

```
.\Out-FINcodedCommand.ps1
```

If it is in a directory that you are not cd to, then the .\ needs to be in front of the whole string

```
.\Downloads\Out-FINcodedCommand-master\Out-FINcodedCommand-master\Out-FINcodedCommand.ps1
```

Answer (score 1):

To complement [SureThing's effective solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60255183/45375) with **background information**:

- By design, as a security measure, **PowerShell - unlike `cmd.exe` - does NOT invoke executables (which includes *scripts*) located in the *current* directory by file *name* only**.

  - **Only executables in the so-called [command-lookup] *path* can be invoked by file name only**, namely only executables located in one of the directories listed in environment variable `Path` (`$env:PATH`). An example is `findstr.exe`, whose  directory, `C:\WINDOWS\system32`, is listed in `$env:PATH`.
- **To invoke executables that are *not* in the command-lookup path, you must use a file *path***:

  - The file path may be *absolute* (full) or *relative* (and may be based on variables).
  - Therefore, **to invoke a script located in the *current* directory, prefix the file name with `.\`** (`.` refers to the current directory), which in the case at hand means
    `.\Out-FINcodedCommand.ps1`. Alternatively, use `./` (PowerShell treats `\` and `/` in paths the same).
  - Separately, if your executable path happens to be quoted and/or contain variable references, you must use `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-) for invocation, e.g., 
    `& ".\some program.exe"`
  - The **rationale** for requiring an explicit path in order to execute a file located in the current directory is that it signals the intent *unambiguously* and thereby prevents *accidental* invocation of a (possibly maliciously placed) executable of the specified name that *also* happens to exist in the current directory even though invocation via `$env:PATH` is intended.