# How to execute powershell code in current directory from terminal?

Tags: powershell, command-line-interface

I run a powershell command like this

```
powershell.exe -File C:\GitHub\project\test\run.ps1 "foo bar"
```

And my current directory is already `C:\GitHub\project\test`. How can I make the `-File` argument just start from the current directory?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply omit the directory path altogether (`powershell.exe -File run.ps1 "foo bar"`) or prefix the script file name with `.\` (`powershell.exe -File .\run.ps1 "foo bar"`) in order to run a script located in the current directory.

Note that in cases where you need to use `-Command` rather than `-File`, the `.\` prefix is *required*, because PowerShell then treats the CLI arguments as *PowerShell code*, and for security reasons PowerShell doesn't permit running scripts in the current directory by file *name* only - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60268174/45375).

See also: [about_PowerShell_exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe?view=powershell-5.1), the documentation of the Windows PowerShell CLI (for PowerShell [Core] v6+, whose executable file name is `pwsh`, the relevant topic is [about_pwsh](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh).)