# Open a command file with Windows PowerShell running it directly

Tags: windows, powershell, shell, powershell-2.0

I want to make a file having Windows Powershell commands. Then I want to open it with windows powershell directly and without pressing any key I want windows powershell start running those commands directly same as command prompy I can make .cmd or .bat file.

For example:
These are two commands or Powershell, I want to save this file. Then I want directly execute this file by powershell. I have tried to save it as **ps1** and **ps2** extension as well but not working. Many methods online are not working. Any solution?

[image]

Comment: `powershell yourfilename.ps1` Type `powershell /?` from a command prompt for more information.

Comment: Do you mean by double clicking?

Comment: If I follow your method @KenWhite, I recieve bug in command prompt. My file name is `Data.ps1`. Error is 
`The term 'Data.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Data.ps1
+ ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Data.ps1:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException`

Comment: and if I use command as `powershell .\Data.ps1`, Error is 
`.\Data.ps1 : File D:\GuiGuiRenderer\Build\GuiGUiBuild\Data.ps1 cannot be loaded. The file
D:\GuiGuiRenderer\Build\GuiGUiBuild\Data.ps1 is not digitally signed. You cannot run this script on the current
system. For more information about running scripts and setting execution policy, see about_Execution_Policies at
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1
+ .\Data.ps1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess`

Comment: `powershell data.ps1` will work fine. If you're getting different results, then [edit] your question to include **exactly** what you're running at the command line. If you're not running it from the command line, then include details of **exactly** how you're trying to run it, including any batch file code if relevant. Expecting us to read your mind to find out what the problem is won't work.

Comment: I don't want to run different one. There is no need to edit the question. The command `powershell Data.ps1` is giving me error message `The term 'Data.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program`. While I have even tried to run command prompt as an admininstrator

Comment: There is only one single command in the command file, command is `$MyVariable=Get-Content .\Path.txt`. This command works fine if I copy paste into powershell IDE directly

Comment: @KenWhite: `powershell data.ps1` is the same as `powershell -Command data.ps1`, which does _not_ work, because you must `.\ `-prefix the script name in that case (`powershell .\data.ps1`); by contrast, this is _not_ required with the `-File` parameter (`powershell -File data.ps1`); note that PowerShell [Core] v6+ now defaults to `-File`, so that `pwsh data.ps1` is the same as `pwsh -File data.ps1` and therefore works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. I use command `powershell.exe` and can directly execute powershell commands within cmd.
`powershell.exe $MyVariable=Get-Content .\Path.txt`
is working fine for me

Answer (score 1):

- PowerShell script files, across all versions, use the `.ps1` filename extension.
- From *within* PowerShell, you can invoke them *directly*, e.g., `.\script.ps1`

  - Note that, unlike in `cmd.exe`, you *must* use `.\` (or a full path) in order to execute a file located in the *current directory* - just `script.ps1` won't work - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60268174/45375) for background information.
- From `cmd.exe`, you must use PowerShell's CLI ([`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) in *Windows PowerShell* / [`pwsh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Pwsh) in *PowerShell [Core] v6+*) in order to execute a script file:

  - `powershell.exe -File script.ps1`
  - `pwsh -File script.ps1` (`-File` may be omitted)

Note that with `-File` the `.\`-prefix is *not* required.

However, if you use `-Command` (`-c`) instead (which is the *default* with `powershell.exe`, whereas `pwsh` now defaults to `-File`), you *do* need the `.\`, because the `-Command` argument(s) are interpreted *as a piece of PowerShell code*, i.e. as if you had submitted it inside a PowerShell session.

You've discovered this [in your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65017637/45375), where you pass a PowerShell command *directly* to the (implied) `-Command` parameter.

Note, however, that it's better to *double-quote* such commands, so as to prevent `cmd.exe` from interpreting certain characters *itself*, which breaks the call.

For instance, the following call would break, if you didn't enclose the `-Command` (`-c`) argument in `"..."`:

```
# From cmd.exe; "..." required.
C:\>powershell.exe -c "Write-Output 'a & b'"
a & b
```

Another important consideration is that you need to escape *embedded* `"` chars. as `\"` for the CLI (even though PowerShell-*internally* you would use `` `" `` or `""`):

```
# From cmd.exe; note the inner " escaped as \"
C:\>powershell.exe -c "Write-Output \"hi there\""
hi there
```